# Convert JsonObject to Photos

Tags: java, jsp, facebook-graph-api, facebook-fql

If execute the coding below, I will be able to retrieve the photos uploaded by myself. For now, I can retrieve the src in my servlet page. However, I am unable to retrieve the src in my jsp page.

1) Is it possible to convert the JsonObject to a Photos object type so I can retrieve information like 'source'?

2) Or I can actually retrieve the src inside my jsp page using the queryResults from my FqlQuery? If so, can you guide me as I tried several ways but it just states I am trying to retrieve invalid property from JsonObject.

```
String query = 
"SELECT pid, src, src_small, src_big, caption FROM photo WHERE owner=" + yourUid;

List<JsonObject> queryResults = 
facebookClient.executeFqlQuery(query, JsonObject.class);

//Doing the below will allow me to retrieve the src in servlet, however
//I want to store it in a list so I can retrieve it inside my jsp page
for(int i=0; i<queryResults.size(); i++)
{
    String photoUrl = queryResults.get(i).getString("src"); 
    // add your code to use photoUrl
}
```

Inside my jsp page, I am using c tags to loop and retrieve out the src of each photo

```
<c:forEach items="${photosList}" var="photo">
    //I want to retrieve the src from the photosList
</c:forEach>
```

Answer (score 0):

I guess if you can get the binary source, then in your JSP `for` loop have an img tag whhere the src in a servlet, passing it your unique id.

This servlet will then stream back the bytes.

```
<c:forEach items="${photosList}" var="photo">
//I want to retrieve the src from the photosList
  <img src='myservlet?pid=${photo.pid}'>
</c:forEach>
```

Comment: I will get the following error... `javax.el.PropertyNotFoundException: The class 'com.restfb.json.JsonObject' does not have the property 'pid'.`

Comment: The reason I used the variable 'pid' is that it was used in your query.  I am giving you a solution not the code.  I will leave that to you.  If you have more trouble please create a new question.